# how to share separate variable instances between method calls for different ids

Tags: php, static, instance-variables

I have a method that activates a promotion which is valid only for one day. The promotion can be selected for ads on the webpage, but it can be clicked only 5 times per day for each ad and the promotion is valid only until midnight.
The function is called whenever the promotion is clicked. I declared the variable as
`static $usedPromotion = 0;` and then I am checking in a condition

```
if ($promotionValidUntilMidnight > $now) {
     if ($usedPromotion <= 5) {
            $usedPromotion += 1;
            ...
      }
}
```

The problem is that the method is called for different ads, with different IDs, and the value of `$usedPromotion` is being increased for the rest of ads and the condition is not being checked.

I am not sure which condition can I apply to make `$usedPromotion = 0;` again, I thought about storing it in a map with the ad id and then removing it, but this can waste a lot of memory..
Would appreciate any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: can the `$usedPromotion` variable not be either an array or object with individual adverts as keys?

Comment: yea sounds like that would work. but even static variables in php generally don't live long (generally they disappear after every request, just like instance members). And since he mentions longer timelines (5 times a day...) he'd need something more persistant i suspect

Comment: It sounds like any common database table could fill this need ? Does your application not already use a database/datastore of some kind ? (mysql, postgres, mongodb, redis, ... something like that)

Comment: but making an associated array wouldn't solve the problem, since at every method call the value of ```$usedPromotions``` will be overwritten

Comment: You should be storing the clicks inside a database.  Query it when its clicked to get the current click count.  Add a date column to the clicks so you can know how many clicks happened in a given day